# SQL JOIN returns query with wrong ids for each row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, inner-join

In my database I have a table named `posts` and a table named `topics`.

Each `post` has a parent `topic`.

In this case `posts.parent_topic` is a foreign key to the associated `topics.id`

I am attemping to do a `JOIN` so that my query will return the correct `topics.topic_title` from the `topics` table. I have been able to successfully do this, however I am noticing that I am no longer getting the correct `posts.id` for anything that is returned.

My query:

```
$posts = $db->query("
    SELECT
      *
    FROM
      posts
    JOIN topics ON
      posts.post_parent_topic = topics.id
    ORDER BY
      posts.created_on DESC
  ")->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

After doing a `var_dump` on the `$posts` variable I am seeing these results:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1) // this id is CORRECT for the post
      'post_parent_topic' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_on' => string '2015-11-03 09:30:40' (length=19)
      'post_title' => string 'Development Standards' (length=21)
      'post_content' => string 'These are the development specifc standards.' (length=44)
      'topic_title' => string 'Code Standards' (length=14)
      'topic_content' => string 'These are the company programming standards.' (length=44)
      'topic_parent_organization' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=12)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1) // this id is INCORRECT for the post, it should be an id of 2 (as it appears in the database)
      'post_parent_topic' => string '1' (length=1)
      'created_on' => string '2015-11-03 09:30:40' (length=19)
      'post_title' => string 'Design Standards' (length=16)
      'post_content' => string 'These are the design specific standards.' (length=40)
      'topic_title' => string 'Code Standards' (length=14)
      'topic_content' => string 'These are the company programming standards.' (length=44)
      'topic_parent_organization' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Why would each post return the same `id`? I need the `id` of the post as it is in my database.

Comment: Is there `id` column in `posts` table?

Comment: are you sure that `id` is from `topics` and not `posts`. generally it's better to first alias each table and field using `AS` that way you can see which field belongs to each table. (ie. `SELECT p.id AS 'posts_id', t.id AS 'topics_id' FROM posts AS p LEFT JOIN topics AS t ON p.post_parent_topic = t.id ORDER BY p.created_on DESC`)

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev yes there is an id column in each table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have `id` column in both `posts` and `topics` tables, you may need to give them aliases to make it unambigious:

Try changing the query to the following:

```
SELECT p.*, t.id AS TopicId, t.topic_title, t.topic_content, t.topic_parent_organization
FROM posts AS p
JOIN topics AS t 
    ON posps.post_parent_topic = t.id
ORDER BY p.created_on DESC
```